# Writing feature tests for a big network software

Tags: linux, testing, functional-testing, stress-testing

I'm working on feature tests for a big network software. Is there any framework for such tests (Linux platform)?

Basically the tests would have the following structure:

1. prepare the system
2. try to do something
3. wait x seconds for results
4. if timeout: cleanup and report error
5. try to do something as user X
6. ...

I was thinking of implementing this directly in Perl, but if there is already some support framework, then it would be much better.

Comment: What sort of "network software" will you be testing?

Comment: @Kimvais A batch system. Does it really matter?

Comment: well, network software can mean an awfully lot of things, ranging from Layer 2 stack to an enterprise application that is now networked when it's data transfer used to mean hauling tapes from location A to B.

Comment: @Kimvais And? When testing a system from outside, it's inner workings are irrelevant.

Comment: Of course, inner workings are irrelevant, but the fact that _what_ you will be testing is quite essential regarding choosing the testing framework.

Comment: @Kimvais That doesn't sound right either. The "what" part is what I will be implementing. What I want from a testing framework is the scaffolding. But I'm getting what you mean. By network I meant asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that every system is different or they look the same from a top-level view, but looking deeper into system you will find blocking issues, i.e. "the devil lies in the details". For this reason we have always implemented our own test-frameworks in order to have full control over the system.

Another point I would like to make is that the code will be read by developers/maintainers many times. Although perl is a great language, it is not intended to be read or easily understood. The guy who wrote it may quit and someone else needs to make adjustments; therefor I would recommend you to use [python](http://www.python.org/) instead for ease of maintainability.

just my 10c...

Comment: @Mark2, speaking from own experience :-), forced to use a 100k lines OO-perl-framework than 1 guy wrote and that 1 guy understand, i.e. impossible to maintain/update. This for something that `git` would solve by default...

Comment: This is more like a comment then an answer. My own experience is that good programmers write good code and bad programmers write bad code. And I have always found python to be completely unreadable (but that is my own point of view).

Comment: you have a point there sortof :-). I do argue for the point to roll your own test-FW due to the ever changing requirements from project managers. Something *out-of-the-box* will never meet all requirements and then you'll start patching the FM, and when the FM updates you'll need to back-port those updates. Will be very messy...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [STAF (Software Test Automation Framework)](http://staf.sourceforge.net/)

It looks like it might be a good fit for what you need.

> The Software Testing Automation Framework (STAF) is an open source, multi-platform, multi-language framework designed around the idea of reusable components, called services (such as process invocation, resource management, logging, and monitoring). STAF removes the tedium of building an automation infrastructure, thus enabling you to focus on building your automation solution. The STAF framework provides the foundation upon which to build higher level solutions, and provides a pluggable approach supported across a large variety of platforms and languages.

And there's an article here: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2004/12/stafstax-tutorial.html